# Creating ServerDeploymentGroup in AWS-CDK that deploys to autoscalling group using codedeploy

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-code-deploy, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a AWS pipeline using aws-cdk (Java language).The phases are as follows:
Source: Codecommit
Build: Codebuild
Deploy: Deploy to Autoscalling group using CodeDeploy

I am struggling to create ServerDeploymentGroup using aws cdk. I have already Autoscalling group created which i want to be used in ServerDeploymentGroup. But Not able to configure this in AWS-CDK. Getting ClassCastException:

Here is my code which is intended for AutoscallingGroup creation and ServerDeploymentGroup creation

```
AutoScalingGroup autoScalingGroup = (AutoScalingGroup) AutoScalingGroup.fromAutoScalingGroupName(this, "autoscallinggroup", "myautscallinggroup");    
        List<AutoScalingGroup> autoScalingGroupList =  new ArrayList<AutoScalingGroup>();
        autoScalingGroupList.add(autoScalingGroup);
        
        ServerDeploymentConfig deploymentConfig = (ServerDeploymentConfig) ServerDeploymentConfig.ALL_AT_ONCE;
        ServerApplication application = ServerApplication.Builder.create(this, "codedeployapplication")
                                     .applicationName("mydeployapplication")
                                     .build();
        
        
        ServerDeploymentGroup deploymentGroup = ServerDeploymentGroup.Builder.create(this, "codedeploymentgroup")
                                                .application(application)
                                                .autoScalingGroups(autoScalingGroupList)
                                                .deploymentGroupName("MyDeploymentGroup")
                                                .deploymentConfig(deploymentConfig)
                                                .installAgent(true)
                                                .role(codeDeployRole)
                                                .build();
```

Here is the exception that I am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class software.amazon.awscdk.services.autoscaling.IAutoScalingGroup$Jsii$Proxy cannot be cast to class software.amazon.awscdk.services.autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup (software.amazon.awscdk.services.autoscaling.IAutoScalingGroup$Jsii$Proxy and software.amazon.awscdk.services.autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Any help regarding this? HOw to solve this issue in aws-cdk?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in AWS CDK code,due to which ServerDeploymentGroup was accepting List of AutoscalingGroup instead of List of IAutoScalingGroup. The bug is fixed in **v1.58.0** release on 12th August.
Now I am able to resolve my above mentioned problem.

Take a look here.
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/9252